# Django serializers create method gets empty validated data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to create a new sheet.

**My serializer:**

```
class PostSandBox(serializers.Serializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return Sheets.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**Viewset:**

```
class Sandbox(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSandBox
```

So my problem is, `validated_data` is always empty.

*How can I solve this?*

Comment: Im not sure where should i call .is_valid. Isnt that createmodelmixin should do it behind the scenes?

Comment: Where exactly do you specify that the model is a `Sheets`?

Comment: I tried to specify in viewset Sandbox by: queryset=Sheets.objects.all() Result is the same

Comment: Perhaps it's not validating properly. What is it returning when you call it?

Comment: is.valid returns True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For working with Django Models you want to use a [`serializers.ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of `serializers.Serializer`.